# check if a string contains a specific word in PHP?

Tags: php

I have this String: `v531123000`
I want test if it contains the string `v531`.

I did it by `strpos` but it doesn't work:

```
$pn = $article->getPartNumber();
if (strpos($pn, 'v531') !== false) {
                $lt=30;
            }
```

Should I search another function not `strpos` to do it ?

Comment: Nope, https://3v4l.org/RWm5R

Comment: So this means that `$pn` is not what you expect. But as you don't output it, we can't help.

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php how to use strpos correctly